# Sinch Curl example to send SMS does not seem to work

Tags: curl, sms-gateway, sinch

I'm trying to use the SMS service of Sinch (as Twilio does not seem to work for me in the Netherlands), so I started a free account with them. But following their 'Get started' wizard and running the supplied `CURL` command only returns me an unspecific error:

> {"errorCode":50000,"message":"Internal Server Error."}

I'd rather not give the exact command I'm using, as it contains a password/key, but the command precisely follows [their spec/example](https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/sending-sms-curl/). E.g. it has this form:

> curl --user "applicationyour_app_key:your_app_secret" --data '{"message":"your_message"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://messagingapi.sinch.com/v1/sms/the_phone_number

I'm using [CygWin](https://www.cygwin.com/) on Windows 8 to run curl.

I DO get an SMS when I use the simple test button in their wizard, but ofcourse I'd want to access it programmatically, and the fact that cUrl doesn't work is a bad indication to me.

Can anybody tell me how to fix this? Perhaps the Sinch people themselves, as on their FAQ they advise you to come here to Stackoverflow :>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sinch dev here, It looks like it's an error in the documentation, the command should be

`curl --user "application\your_app_key:your_app_secret"` [...] with a backslash between `application` and your key, sorry for the inconvenience :)

Comment: Thanks! I had already tried a version with a slash too, but that was a forward slash. I even believe that is what [your wizard](https://www.sinch.com/dashboard/#/quickstart) (link behind login) generated then. But I just retried and it is generating it correctly now. Using curl within Cygwin on Windows also helped me, since running curl it under simple Windows `cmd` also has some different syntax..